# MAC: Stop launch process. (Logmein Hamachi, not in system preferences)

Tags: macos, mac, boot, logmein

I simply cannot find a way to stop LogMeIn Hamachi loading at launch. I use it rarely but don't want to un-install it yet it bugs me that it's there.

[image: Launch Window]

As you can see, LogMeIn Hamachi is not here...

It also happens to not be in the inbuilt preferences panel. Hmm, almost like they don't want it to not startup...

Looking in activity monitor there is

[image: Appmon]

I can only assume "launchd(1)" Means the process happens at startup so that's my only guess. Any help would be appreciated. Otherwise I'm tossing it out the window and keeping the installer till I need it again... Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd weigh up the amount of irritation at it always being there vs. the amount of irritation when you're on holiday in Ibiza/Aruba etc, try to get back to your home machine... & realise it's not running... :/  [I've done it, I now let it run]

Comment: As the fact you're using it more I guess for it's intended purpose... I tend to use it only for creating an IP for (game) servers for me and a few friends to play on rather than renting a VPN. It more irritates me that they don't want you to turn it off, I'd rather have the option... :p And remember me from the other question? Tehe....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parent process (`launchd`, process ID 1) is the second process started by the machine (after `kernel_task`, ID 0). It loads up launch agents (that run at login for each user) and launch daemons (that run at boot for the whole system).

What you need to disable or delete is the launch agent corresponding to LogMeIn Hamachi. It’s in the folder `/Library/LaunchAgents/`. You can go to the folder in the Finder by using the menu item Go > Go to Folder, and pasting in the path.

If you delete the file `com.logmein.hamachimb.plist` in the LaunchAgents folder, then log out/reboot, you’ll find that LogMeIn Hamachi won’t load when you log in anymore.

Alternatively, you can disable the launch agent with the Terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.hamachimb.plist
```

Comment: It's not in that folder?...

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, turns out there is two 'Library' folders, was in the other.

Comment: Hope it worked for you! If it does, don’t forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: As a sidenote, I followed the advice at http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110724044801607 and changed  /Library/LaunchAgents/com.logmein.hamachimb.plist->OnDemand to KeepAlive so that the quit 
 worked.